# how to initialize new textbox in specific position in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am using InkCanvas control and I want to add a textbox in it as a child in specific position I succeeded to add it but not in the correct position ? how I can transform it or any another method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the attached properties `Left` and `Top` like so:

```
var myTextBox = new TextBox();
myCanvas.Children.Add( myTextBox );
InkCanvas.SetLeft( myTextBox, someLeftValue );
InkCanvas.SetTop( myTextBox, someTopValue );
```

Comment: Nope inkcanvas doesn't drive from canvas and in hasn't have .left and .top

Comment: @salamonti: Yes it does (have those methods), I just looked in the docs. It is a static method, not an instance method. It does not derive from Canvas however, which is why I previously removed that line. Attached properties are used by calling a static method in the parent class. You use them like I show in the last two lines, not as instance methods.

Comment: It has those attached methods, but you should be calling them on the `InkCanvas` class, not Canvas.

Comment: @salamonti Please edit your question to add the code or XAML - it's very hard to diagnose your problem through sheer guesswork.

Comment: in the tag i tag with c# not xaml

Answer (score 1):

The [InkCanvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas.aspx) isn't a panel type (note it inherits from FrameworkElement), but it does contain attached properties (as Ed S. mentioned) that let you position children as though it were a Canvas panel:

```xml
<InkCanvas>
  <TextBox InkCanvas.Top="50" InkCanvas.Left="50"/>
</InkCanvas>
```

Alternatively, you can also insert a panel as the child of the InkCanvas. For example:

```xml
<InkCanvas>
  <Canvas>
    <TextBox Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="50"/>
  </Canvas>
</InkCanvas>
```